# ElementName not working when assigning DataTemplate from code behind?

Tags: silverlight, binding, resources, user-controls, datatemplate

I am trying to access Control using ElementName from DataTemplate that is used in different UserControl (Resources) than defined (in xaml).

Imagine this situation:

MyUserControl.xaml with following DataTemplate in resources:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
   <DataTemplate x:Key="SomeTemplate">
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text, ElementName=TextElement}"/>
   </DataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <TextBlock x:Name="TextElement" Text="IT WORKS! (not...)"/>
</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

MyUserControlWrapper.xaml

```
<ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter" Content="{Binding SomeContent}"/>
```

and in code behind of MyUserControlWrapper.xaml i set ContentTemplate of ContentPresenter from MyUserControl.xaml:

something like:

```
ContentPresenter.ContentTemplate = (DataTemplate)childView.Resources["SomeTemplate"];
```

---

Is it possible to use ElementName from resources that are defined outside UserControl?

How DataTemplate searches for ElementName in same UserControl then? Maybe its possible to set something like DataContext for DataTemplate itself for ElementName to work, without messing with DataContext that is sent to controls used inside Template?

Comment: To help you get to a solution it would be better is you show how a "MyUserContolWrapper" is placed.  Its unclear how it relates to MyUserControl at present.

Comment: I am constructing initial view in code behind and place it inside Wrapper's ContentPresenter. Wrapper sort of 'enhances' basic view with some features like Toolbar, Sidebar, etc.

So wrapped view might look like
[ Toolbar              ]
[Side][  Original view ]
[ InfoFrame           ]

And in original view you can control some parts of wrapped content using templates. That is done by defining strict-name DataTemplates. Imagine like wrapper defines design of InfoFrame (borders, placement, etc.) but information itself in InfoFrame is loaded from original view's DataTemplate x:Key="InfoContent".

Answer (score 1):

You need to review the concepts related to [Namescopes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189026(v=VS.95).aspx).

Briefly names are scoped at the point where a Xaml resources are loaded.  For example each UserControl will each load their own Xaml and therefore have their own namescope.   In your case you asking `MyUserControlWrapper` to find a name that its `LoadComponent` has not seen.

Comment: Is there a way to assign/set Namescope of any control to DataTemplate from code-behind?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can just walk up the VisualTree using RelativeSource and FindAncestor?
There is a nice presentation of different binding variants here:
http://www.wpfwiki.com/Default.aspx?Page=WPF%20Q5.3&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1